# iOS uiwebview with popup alert and tap to retry option on internet connection issue when user not connected

Tags: ios, swift3, uiwebview, popup, xcode8

I am beginner for iOS app development, implemented UIWebView, now i need a popup alert when user is not connected to internet and thereby also have tap to retry button to check if connection is available. How can i implement this feature in iOS using swift3 while on implementing webview.

Help me. please.Thanks..

Comment: Use Reachability for network status. https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: thanks gagan.. the solution you provided helped me a lot.